# How do I disable the boot splash screen, and only show kernel and boot text instead?

Tags: boot, startup, plymouth

I'd like to be able to disable the Ubuntu splash screen that I see on boot with the indicator meter of progress, and replace that with a text-only readout of the boot up process (such as you can get by hitting the `esc` key during the splash screen).  Is this possible?

*I am not asking to disable X and get to text-only login, I"m asking how to deactivate the "Ubuntu" loading screen with the dots, so that I can see text output from the boot process - processes being started, kernel messages, etc.  When I wrote this question I was not asking how to disable X altogether, only the boot splash screen.*

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Yes. Edit `/etc/default/grub` (using `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`), and remove the `"quiet splash"` from the Linux command line:

Here's what it looks like by default:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Make it look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

After this run `sudo update-grub2`

Also from the GRUB menu, if you want to do this temporarily, you can hit <kbd>E</kbd> on a line to edit it, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot the kernel line.

Make sure you don't have `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` package installed.

Comment: In addition to this, if you want to see the kernel startup messages you'll probably want to remove the "quiet" boot option too.

Comment: This worked.  I wanted the kernel startup messages too, so by removing the "quiet" option too, it did what I want it to do.  :)

Comment: And possibly uncomment line `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"`

Comment: +1 for pointing to the `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` package. (Check if you have it using `dpkg -s plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text`. If you want to remove it you can use `apt-get remove plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text`)

Comment: *Why* would I want to remove `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text`? What's this package's role in this? Doesn't it work if I don't? Could you give us some more context? -- In Xenial Xerus Lubuntu removal of that package would uninstall `lubuntu-core` and `lubuntu-desktop`, which seems pretty bad. (So it would be nice to avoid that.)

Comment: For me, uninstalling of `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` was not necessary to have the start messages back.

Comment: I can't remember if it was necessary at the time (This question is about 6 years old now).

Comment: "Command 'gksu' not found, did you mean:

  command 'ksu' from deb heimdal-clients (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1)
  command 'ksu' from deb krb5-user (1.17-6ubuntu4)
  command 'gosu' from deb gosu (1.10-1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>"

Comment: gksu is obsolete. just use `sudo nano` or whatever cli editor you want to edit the file.

Answer (score -1):

So, I couldn't get this to work in Ubuntu 16.10 of 17.04. I used grub-customizer as well as editing the /etc/default/grub file directly (and using update-grub2 after). All the other things I could find had the same answer, remove quiet splash.

As it worked on a 16.04 system, I decided to compare the grub.cfg files and found an entry in the 17.04 grub.cfg file which said "vt.handoff". I found the following entry on this parameter;
[What is vt.handoff=7 parameter in grub.cfg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32999/what-is-vt-handoff-7-parameter-in-grub-cfg)

Eventually I edited the grub.cfg file (which you shouldn't do because thats whatts update-grub2 is for, it will generate the grub.cfg file), but this seemed to work!

ps. removing plymooth did nothing on my system, so I added it back in.

Comment: What *exactly* did you change in which file? You mention `grub.cfg` (probably `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) and `vt.handoff` but you don't specify what you did about it. FYI, if you did what I think you did, that change can be done better in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` plus an invocation of `update-grub`.