# I am getting the black screen in startup

Tags: 12.04, startup

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Actually I upgraded my system from 11.10 to 12.04 using terminal. At first it works fine after some days, I am getting the black screen while starting the system. *I am able to login after 4 to 5 times of rebooting every day.* Some times it takes 10 times to login. I think this is because of me running a wrong command on the system

and i tried other answers in askubuntu.com it doesn't worked for me.

what am I supposed to do? Please do let me know

this is a ubuntu system and not booted with any cd and upgraded my Ubuntu version using terminal.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output when you remove `quiet splash` from the grub? Check here for a temporary method: http://askubuntu.com/a/33420/169736