# GRUB2 shows purple screen on bootup

Tags: boot, grub2

When booting my (even w/o problems slow) computer (Raring x64 only, GRUB2), GRUB shows me an purple screen after selection (timeout 0) and before actually booting Ubuntu. This is really annoying because it stays there for about 15 seconds, which is actually more than it needs to start GRUB and boot Ubuntu.

My `/etc/default/grub` (comments removed):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

What can I do to avoid this problem? I didn't change the file except setting the timeout to `0` because I thought it's waiting 10 seconds, but doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got fixed somehow. I don't know where it came from and where it went.

Answer (score 1):

Whack {Esc} when it appears and it will clear, and show you line by line what's going on.

To permanently remove it so you can always see all the fiddly bits, see [How do I disable the boot splash screen, and only show kernel and boot text instead?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen)

Comment: Neither hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> nor removing quiet splash has an effect. The <kbd>ESC</kbd> only has effect when the Ubuntu boot screen shows up.

Comment: Edit /etc/default/grub (using sudo nano /etc/default/grub) [or substitute your favorite editor for nano], and remove the "quiet splash" from the Linux command line.

After this run sudo update-grub2

Comment: That's what I actually did.

Comment: This would disable Plymouth, but it doesn't seem to be related to Plymouth.