# Ubuntu start up problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 13.10, startup

I have a relatively fresh install of Saucy Salamander, however I'm experiencing quite some difficulty when starting up my computer.

My computer seems to crash / freeze more often than not between the grub "choose your OS" and logging in to Ubuntu. Most of the time I see a purple or black screen after pressing enter and it never progresses from there. Sometimes it freezes at the log in screen after the Ubuntu drum sound. Least often, it freezes just a few seconds after logging in.

If I get to the point of having logged in, and it has not frozen after a minute, the system seems to be stable, and I haven't experienced any problems in the normal usage. So whatever the issue is, it seems to occur after grub loader and before log in.

My system specs:

- AMD fx 8120, 8 core 3.1ghz
- 8 gb ram
- OCZ 60 gb SSD (<- problematic Ubuntu)
- Seagate Barracuda 500 gb (<- Win7, no problems booting)
- Asrock 990FX extreme 3 mobo
- Radeon HD 6970 video card (Ubuntu uses the proprietary driver)

In short: I must restart my computer 5 to 10 times before I can log into Ubuntu properly. I have no problem loading windows on my other HD. I see no freezing / crash if I do manage to log in successfully.

What can cause this? How to fix?

Comment: Either you're fx-card or your ssd 'causes problems here. To determine what component is causing trouble Try the following to deactivate teh plymouth boot screen.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst