# Disable GUI at boot time

Tags: boot, gui

I want to disable GUI at boot time. I followed these steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Find out this line:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

1. Change it to:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"

1. Update Grub:

> sudo update-grub

1. Reboot

but nothing happened! I can access GUI remotely using xrdp. What I'm missing here?

Comment: If you want to disable splash screen, you should delete `quiet splash` and leave `""`. http://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst

Comment: Hello mayby this help [>>Try this<<](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9644518#post9644518)

Comment: @desgua tried it. didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you make a mistake. You should put the option `"text"` at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` (not to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`) ([1](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/))

Comment: i run this command but nothing changed :(

Comment: I think may be you made a mistake: you should put the option `"text"` at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` (not to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="")

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/

Comment: Thanks! turns out that remote access (xrdp) still use GUI even if it's disabled!

Comment: So you have to uninstall it?