# How can I see tty during shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, log, tty

The shutdown of my ubuntu 12.04 never terminates. (It's been running for one hour, showing the ubuntu word with the rotating dots below: it's still alive.)

Right after I initiate the shutdown, the screen briefly (very briefly) show a tty with information on it. I'd like to see it.

How can I see the information on tty1 during shutdown?

(I already tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 in vain.)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst

Comment: @Rinzwind had already seen 33416, but I'd like to see what is on the screen right now, not the screen of a future shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to see shut down messages?

Usually all you need to do is to press `Esc` when the Ubuntu logo shows up.