# Cannot boot 15.04 from Grub2 on UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, uefi, windows-10

Here is how my system is set up (GPT partitioning):

- First 32 GB: Windows 10 Professional x64 partitions and EFI FAT partition
- Next 24 GB: Ubuntu 15.04 x64 root ext4 partition
- Next 8 GB: swap
- Rest of hard drive (approx 430 GB): NTFS partition for shared data storage

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W520 (4 years old) with a recently refreshed bios.

The problem is that I see three options in Grub:

- `Ubuntu`
- `Advanced options for Ubuntu`
- `Windows Boot Manager`

Ubuntu and any of its advanced options simply hang after a few seconds with no disk access, and Windows appears to have a UEFI boot error.

I installed both Windows and Ubuntu normally, with the exception of setting up proper partitioning.

Can someone please explain what the problem is, and how to fix it? Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu? Did you leave Windows fast start up on which is always on hibernation? Grub only boots working Windows that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk.  What video chip does your system have? It may need boot parameter for video. Can you use second entry which may be firs tin Advanced options. Try recovery boot .

Comment: Also try booting with `quiet splash` temporarily disabled as described in http://askubuntu.com/a/33420/40581 you should be able to see where it hangs. Upload a photo if you cannot figure out what it means.

Comment: @oldfred I was not able to boot Windows at all after installing Ubuntu; before that I was. It says it can't open the EFI file. I did try to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode, and that did work, but I wasn't able to do anything. After an unsuccessful attempt at fixing it by reinstalling Ubuntu, I'm trying to reinstall everything with legacy boot, since both OS's support it, and it's inherently much simpler.