# It takes 1 1/2 minutes to log off

Tags: logout

when I log off it takes a minute and a half because it says "session 2 has a stop order", I have no idea where it came from and how to correct it, I am fairly new to Ubuntu. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!   Where does it say that "session 2 has a stop order?"  Does it pop up with a dialog box, or is this in a black screen or what?  Could you share the exact error message, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same Problem. It occurred after clean install Ubuntu 16.04. I have looked several hours for any information and tried several things. Nothing helped. It was really annoying. In Ubuntu 15.10 the shutdown was: switch and off in less than 1 sec. Now it took at least 1,30 sec. Finally I figured out, after lots of troubleshooting, that (after disable the Ubuntu boot splash screen) a certain stop-job was running that made the shutdown slow. (Thanks to Alex!) Then I got this error report: "a stop job is running for make remote cups printers available locally" Then I tried this:

```
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed.service
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```

and to verify:

```
sudo systemctl status cups-browsed
sudo systemctl is-enabled cups-browsed
```

and it finally worked! Shutdown was now as good and fast as ever. (you can find this troubleshooting on: "[The Annoying Cups Browsed](http://ec-cwang.github.io/system/The-Annoying-Cups-Browsed.html)" at the ec-cwang´s Blog!)

This might be important for those this solution is not helpful: How to find out your running stop jobs, just look up: "[How do I disable the boot splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst)" on Ask Ubuntu. Then, if you start Ubuntu you get the typical Linux running command signs. If you shut Ubuntu down, mention the output. It shows you at the end what kind of stop job slows down your shutdown procedure.