# Ubuntu won't load after failed update

Tags: dual-boot

I was updating ubuntu 16.04 but had to shut it down before the update finished, and when I tired restarting it, I got stuck on the purple screen right after the grub menu. No progress is shown other than the caps lock button blinking. 
How so I fix it without needing to reinstall it? Can i fix it through my windows boot?

Comment: That likely means a kernel panic. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst) for how to show the boot log, and then [edit] your question to include the last few log entries.

Comment: I was able to get around it by going in to the advanced settings for ubuntu and opening a previous version of ubuntu. Didn't know I could do that. Thank you for your help