# Very slow boot time, seems to be caused mainly by systemd-udevd.service

Tags: boot, performance, systemd

[image: systemd-analyze blame output]

As seen from above image, it takes a lot of time for my system to boot up. In particular

```
1min 2.481s systemd-udevd.service
```

I have 8GB RAM and i5-2540M processor, 320 GB HDD.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/33420/11953) answer and disable splash boot. This way you will be able to see why the system is taking such a long time to boot. Add a screenshot to your question, of the screen where it gets stuck for a longer period.