# How to add a custom boot screen to Ubuntu Minimal?

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have disabled the boot screen/splash screen in my Ubuntu Mini installation it has just the core system with Openbox and Xorg installed, it is upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. I have been wondering if I could add a custom boot logo, even if just a simple label with text, but preferably an image.

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst) is how I removed the boot logo in the first place.

Comment: @guiverc and this will work for ubuntu minimal?

Comment: You don't have a minimal system if you've added Xorg, `openbox` & likely other packages; but the plymouth screen was no doubt added already when you changed your system into a desktop (Xorg/openbox) type system (if not before).  The `plymouth` screen is what hides the text boot messages the linux kernel provides by default (ie. it's the Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu etc logo page users usually see - it's the equivalent of a logo & dots, or simple graphic only that hides the kernel boot messages).  It's shown before the greeter/DM allows you to login.