Kubuntu 24.04 LTS doesn't boot right after install. Grub option allows boot but breaks brightness and night color control. Intel integrated graphics
OS: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS
Laptop: Lenovo IdeaPad 3 17IAU7
Hardware: running lspci command returns:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-U15 Host and DRAM Controller (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 04)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P SATA AHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCI Express x1 Root Port #10 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc 2450 NVMe SSD [HendrixV] (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
03:00.0 SD Host controller: Genesys Logic, Inc GL9750 SD Host Controller (rev 01)

I have been battling this problem for over 15+ hours so I would ask you to read everything I have tried so far before I am told basic stuff I have tried already.
Problem: after installing Kubuntu 24.04 LTS with bootable USB (btw, everything works during the Live USB session), I restart and the very first boot works. I am able to log in and everything works (brightness control, night light control, wifi, etc everything). HOWEVER, without touching literally anything, just clicking shutdown or reboot on that first boot after install (this way I can rule out any of my inputs being at fault), it goes completely dark upon boot. No log in screen, no grub, no logo, no nothing. Dark screen.
In addition, the problem remains the same whether or not some installation options (such as, disk format type ex4 or any other, or download updates alongside or not) are applied or not. I have tried reinstalling Kubuntu more than 5 times already choosing different options, the same problem always happens. It is also worth mentioning that I disabled secure boot on the BIOS but the same problems always happens.
I have tried boot-repair several times. I used Recommended Repair. Grub then appears on boot, but on clicking the top option for the kernels it goes dark screen again. I click then the 2nd option, the most recent kernel on the list but on recovery mode. Now it will boot, except the following things that worked perfectly on the first boot after install now stop working: brightness control, night color control (basically both have to do with screen display stuff). I insist two work just fine on those two other situations (Live USB and first boot after install). Not a software problem (i.e., tried separate DDC software to try to regain brightness control and it just doesn't recognize the screen).
Recovery mode is, as far as my understanding goes, similar or equivalent to adding the option "nomodeset" to Grub. With that option added to Grub, the system also boots without specifically clicking recovery mode, but brightness and night color will as a result not work. Both "nomodeset" and Recovery Mode break the system features in the exact same way (losing both brightness and night color) and it's not really usable.
I am aware that similar issues have been posted on this website and others. I have read all of those that I could find, to no avail. Most of the info online of people having similar issues are from users having NVIDIA dedicated graphics, which I DON`T have (see hardware above). Please help me.
Summary: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS won't boot right after first ever boot (itself after install), dark screen no logo on boot no nothing. Boot-repair doesn't fix it. Grub "nomodeset" or Recovery Mode will allow boot but break brightness control and night color control. Please help me.

have you seen this https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/currently-supported-releases/kubuntu-24-04-nitpick-noble-lts/post-installation-az/679711-does-not-reboot-after-update-24 and if you need help with grub https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen-and-only-show-kernel-and-boot-text-inst

I'm literally crying. This solved my problem, thank you so much!!!

Pls write an answer and specify what you did so that others that have this problem can find it.

one more thing, after a bit of time you can accept your answer, pls do.

I was able to solve this conundrum by editing the grub config file. I used the following command to edit grub config:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

And I changed this line from:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash'

(I assume " and ' are equivalent and you may have a pair of a kind " " or the other ' '). To this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=''

Then I saved the changes with sudo update-grub2 and rebooted and it works now!
Thanks to user @amar for giving me the solution!
