# Where can I find the meaning of "ro"?

Tags: grub2

I'm having trouble booting my netbook so I'm looking at the grub boot parameters.

I know what splash, quite and vt.handoff=7 do. However I can't find any documentation anywhere about what ro does and why it's there, even though it appears in most examples of grub start up code.

Where can I find documentation about ro?

I assume it means read only. Though docs would ease my mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ro means 'mount the file system as read-only'.

the reason this is done is because fsck (the file system checker) should never be run on a read/write file system.

it's a default for a very good reason, and i would be very wary of changing it.

Comment: also you might find this interesting if you're exploring your boot options: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/10-boot-time-parameters-you-should-know-about-the-linux-kernel.html

Comment: As a sidenote, in theory you could do without specifying **ro**, because the kernel image defaults to this option (script `init`: `readonly=y`). And after the boot-time scripts have done their work (mounting, fsck, logo...), the partition is remounted (`mountall`) as per options in `/etc/fstab` (which usually means it is **rw**).

Answer (score 2):

Boot options can be handled by either the kernel itself or the init script in an [initrd/initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs).

The options that are handled as part of the ['vanilla'](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/what-is-vanilla-kernel-79388/#post411269) kernel are documented on [this page](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) (can also be found other places as well, but that was the first one I found). The boot parameters handled by Ubuntu's initramfs can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man7/casper.7.html).

The vt.handoff parameter is a bit weird. What it does is explained in [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/34487/33286):

> For a smooth boot process, we want to display something other than a
>   black screen as early as possible and leave it on screen until the
>   desktop is ready.  `vt.handoff=7` is part of this.  We have the boot
>   loader display an aubergine background (we wanted to have an Ubuntu
>   logo as well, but there are problems with different aspect ratios
>   between the boot loader and the real system, so this is the next best
>   thing).  `vt.handoff=7` then causes the kernel to maintain the current
>   contents of video memory on virtual terminal 7, which is a new
>   "transparent" VT type.  The first time that the kernel is told to
>   switch away from VT 7, either from Plymouth or manually (Alt-F1,
>   etc.), these contents are lost and VT 7 reverts to text mode.

I could only find a description of it from bug reports, but [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/689606) tells it's origins:

> vt.handoff is a module parameter introduced in an Ubuntu-specific SAUCE patch by
>   Andy Whitcroft, ...It was written expressly for use in the Ubuntu boot process...

Because of this, any documentation would probably be with the module source (if such documentation exists).